# Is frequent polling going to create problems on an ASP.Net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, threadpool, polling

I have an ASP.Net page which polls for a session variable called 'Progress' every 5 seconds by calling a web service method from JavaScript as in code below. This polling starts after a certain button is clicked whose click event on client-side is 'ButtonClick' even in JavaScript code shown here.

**My question is**: Due to a limited thread pool size for ASP.Net, can such frequent polling result in lower throughput and request timeouts, when many users are using this ASP.Net page?

**Web Service Method for Polling**

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public string GetProgress()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
         if (currentContext.Session["Progress"] != null)
            {
                return currentContext.Session["Progress"].ToString() ;
            }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

**JavaScript for Polling used to call above web service method from an ASP.Net page**

```
   function ButtonClick() {
      StartProgressPoll();
    }

   function StartProgressPoll() {
              t = setInterval(GetOpProgress, 5000);
          }

   function GetOpProgress() {
            WebApplication1.WebService1.GetProgress(Success, Failure);
        }
```

Comment: How are you defining "many" users? But regardless, I can't imagine a tiny request every 5 seconds causing much of an issue, if your site is designed to handle your normal page traffic already.

Comment: Can't tell without knowing your architecture behind. But that's what load tests are for, try your code, with your architecture, check when it slows down/breaks. People on the Internet can't give you a more accurate answer than the tests you can make.

Comment: @JoeEnos, By many users I mean something like 50 users using that page and clicking on that button. But you are right the web service method is a very quick call since its only reading a session variable.

Comment: With only 50 users, there should be no chance at all of any resource problems, if you have any kind of halfway-decent hardware and network. You should be fine with 100 times that much traffic.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, Yes you are right. I will need to load test my page.

Comment: @JoeEnos, Can you please write your comment in an answer, so I can mark it as an answer? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From my comments:

I can't imagine a tiny request every 5 seconds causing much of an issue, if your site is designed to handle your normal page traffic already.

With only 50 users, there should be no chance at all of any resource problems, if you have any kind of halfway-decent hardware and network. You should be fine with 100 times that much traffic.